# Are Revealed Modules Duplicated Upon Every Require Statement?

Tags: node.js

For example, suppose we have the file `required-module.js`:

```
var RevealedModule = function()({
   var count = 0;

   var incrementCount = function (){
     return count++;
   }

   incrementCount(); //sets `count` equal to 1

   return {
      incrementCount: incrementCount
   }
})();

module.exports = RevealedModule;
```

Now suppose that in BOTH `file1.js` and `file2.js` we have at the top

```
var RevealedModule = require('required-module.js');
```

**Questions:**

1. How many instances are there now of RevealedModule?  That is, is there just one instance that is being simultaneously referred to by all of these files, or are there now 3 separate instances?
2. Is the private variable `count` in each of these instances now equal to `1` or `3`?

Answer (score 3):

A module is only loaded once. So even if you return a self-executing function in `module.exports`, it will only execute one time ever.

From the documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching

> Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means (among other things) that every call to require('foo') will get exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same file.

Here is the full node.js module loader process described in detail: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together

Comment: So just to confirm: the (private) value of `count` is `1`?

Comment: I've provided all the info you need. I think it'd be instructive for you to run the code and find out for yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

There is only one instance, so you'll get that one each time you require().  Here's a nice explanation:

http://willi.am/blog/2014/10/12/understanding-nodes-require-function